# Android Setting up Short Videos as Profile Pictures Using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I found the [new feature](http://newsroom.fb.com/news/2015/09/improving-mobile-profiles/)  which will come soon in Facebook.

Is there any update in Facebook SDK to upload Video same as [Profile Picture](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture) Uploading?

Anyone know about this?

Answer (score 0):

At the current point in time, the method to upload a profile video is whitelisted.

Check the roadmap/blog for any new features.